# Dapper.Contrib AS Entity, Why it fails?

Tags: c#, inheritance, dapper-contrib

Iam planning to use Contrib with dapper to make my classes in desktop applications look like this

```
public abstract class DB : IDisposable
{
    public virtual long Insert()
    {
        using (var db = ConFactory.GetConnection())
        {
            db.Open();
            return db.Insert(this);
        }
    }
// ... and other CRUD operations 
}
```

then any Concept class will inherits from DB class; like this

```
[Table("test")]
public class Test : DB
{
    [Key]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

using Test class

```
using (Test t = new Test { Name = textBox2.Text })
{
    textBox1.Text = t.Insert().ToString();
}
```

this sample always fails and gives me

> SQL logic error near ")": syntax error

**BUT** when I implement `Insert()` method inside child class it works well !!!
the problem is: my code contains lot of classes, rewrite All CUD operations is so disturbing, 
any idea to solve this with less code?

Comment: I would strongly advise against putting anything into your domain classes. Keep them clean and lean.

Comment: OK Thanks I'll keep that in mind :), what about this? is it clean enough?

Comment: If you run a SQL Trace, what was the SQL being submitted to the database?

Comment: I cannot find good SQL tracer works well with dapper & SQLite !!! do you have one?

Comment: https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a better way to solve this... which is more flexible and more pro i think.
I'll put the solution here ... soon on github

the solution based on Extension methods, to inject CUD operation with only concept classes I proposed `IDbTable` base class

```
public abstract class IDbTable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // do disposing if you need
    }
}

public static class DB
{
    public static long Insert<T>(this T entity) where T : IDbTable
    {
        using (var db = ConFactory.GetConnection())
        {
                db.Open();
                return db.Insert(entity);
        }
    }
    public static void Delete<T>(this T entity) where T : IDbTable
    {
            using (var db = ConFactory.GetConnection())
            {
                db.Open();
                db.Delete(entity);
            }
    }
    public static void Update<T>(this T entity) where T : IDbTable
    {
            using (var db = ConFactory.GetConnection())
            {
                db.Open();
                SqlMapperExtensions.Update(db, entity);
            }
    }

    public static T Get<T>(int id)
    {
        using (var db = ConFactory.GetConnection())
        {
            db.Open();
            return db.Get<T>(id);
        }
    }
}
```

ok this is all

when any class inherits from `IDbTable` base class, it have insert, update  and delete method as extenssion

```
[Table("test")]
public class Test : IDbTable
{
    [Key]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

.......

```
Test t = new Test { Name = textBox2.Text };
textBox1.Text = t.Insert().ToString();
```

AND it WORKS fine !!!

any suggestion to improve will be appreciated.